# Threads are conflicting in django with each other

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-models

I am getting a strange problem in my django app. In my app, I have a model A like this

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and another model B which is using model A foreign key like this

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have a view where I generate a report where I have value of `ModelA` object and I want all `ModelB` object created against that `ModelA' object. I am doing this like this

```
obj_list = ModelB.objects.filter(modelA=modelA_object)
```

The problem which I am getting is that some times (not always), I get ModelB objects which are not related to that `modelA_object`. In face, it is related to some other `modelA_object`. 
For example, I have two `modelA` object `A1 and A2`. And some `modelB` object `B1 and B2`. Here `B1` is using `A1` foreign key and `B2` is using `A2` foreign key. In normal case, when I run following code

```
obj_list = ModelB.objects.filter(modelA=A1)
```

`obj_list` will contain `B1`. But Sometimes (not always) I get `B2` in that list. Its seems that two request/threads for report are conflicting with each other. It does not happens often and when it happens, when I generate report second time, it show correct result. I am not writing any thing in DB in view where I am generating report. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Original Code:

Task Model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    job = models.ForeignKey(JobPosition)
```

Test Conducted Model:

```
class TestConducted(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    applied = models.ForeignKey(CandidateApplied)
    result = models.ForeignKey(TestResults)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    dynamic_Lifts = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    not_cap_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_invoiced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modified = AutoLastModifiedField(('modified'))
```

CandidateApplied Model:

```
class CandidateApplied(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    format = models.ForeignKey(TestFormat)
    jobposition = models.ForeignKey(JobPosition,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)
    barcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
```

There can be only one CandidateApplied model object for a specific TestConducted model object.
This is how I am accessing tasks

```
var_conducted = "TestConducted Model Object"
temp_tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(job=var_conducted.applied.jobposition.id).values_list \
            ('name', 'description').order_by('id')
```

Here `jobposition` is another model which is like this

```
class JobPosition(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    SOC_Code = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    PDC = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Values.CUSTOM_PDC_OPTIONS)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    billed_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    monthly_invoice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Django itself is threadsafe, so any thread-safety bugs are in your own code. You probably need to show exactly where you are defining and using that `obj_list`.

Comment: @DanielRosemanI I have provided my original code with models.

Comment: @e4c5 I have provided my original code with models.

Comment: @e4c5 There can be only one CandidateApplied model object for a specific TestConducted model object.